# call page method from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, methods, code-behind

I have a javascript that deposits icons based upon a code-behind data retriever. I loop the map script to refresh the map on the client side.  I have the script refiring on an interval just fine. But it needs to re-fire the data retriever which is on the server side in the code behind.  I like the idea of using Page Methods, but can't quite get that connected - the method in my code behind will only seem to fire if I reload-refresh and I don't want that.

Ideally, at the start of the javascript is where I want the data retrieve to be re-fired along with the javascript execution.

Desired sequence would be : data refreshed -> map-icons re-positioned

Here is my javascript - with a COMMENTED line as to where I THINK the data retriever re-fire should occur in the sequence.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // map creation - setup
       var mapbaselayerholder = "mapbox.streets";
       var TeleMaticsIcon = L.icon({ iconUrl: '../../MapIcons/truck23.png', });
        var addressPointsTeleMatics = '';
        var MarkersAsClustersForTeleMatics = '';

            addressPointsTeleMatics = '';
            MarkersAsClustersForTeleMatics = '';

            L.mapbox.accessToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
            var DaveMap = L.mapbox.map('mapMine', mapbaselayerholder)
            .setView([41.874116, -87.664099], 5);

            var options = L.control.layers({
                'Street': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
                'SatStr': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets-satellite'),
            }).setPosition('topleft').addTo(DaveMap);


            //THIS IS THE START OF THE JS on a TIMER (as per the interval in the setTimeout line at the bottom of the script) 
            display();

            function display()
            {

                //THIS IS WHERE I THINK/GUESS the re-freshing of the code-behind data retriever should be fired 
                // the code-behind method that retrieves the data is in the next line (TeleMatics()) 

                addressPointsTeleMatics = JSON.parse('<%=TeleMatics() %>');
                MarkersAsClustersForTeleMatics = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({ showCoverageOnHover: true, maxClusterRadius: 15, spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true });


                // TeleMatics Grab Loop
                for (var i = 0; i < addressPointsTeleMatics.length; i++) {

                    var V = '';
                    V = addressPointsTeleMatics[i];
                    markerTeleMatics = L.marker(new L.LatLng(V.Latitude, V.Longitude), { icon: TeleMaticsIcon, title: 'Truck # ' + V.vehicleID }).addTo(DaveMap);
                    MarkersAsClustersForTeleMatics.addLayer(markerTeleMatics);

                }
                // Actually Display the Propagated Layers that have been populated from the FOR loops for each icon set 
                DaveMap.addLayer(MarkersAsClustersForTeleMatics);
                setTimeout("display()", 5000);
            }

</script>
```

HERE IS THE CODE-BEHIND METHOD ITSELF that I need to be re-fired

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string TeleMatics()
    {


        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Wayne01"].ConnectionString);

                string CompanyAllString = "Select vehicleID, Latitude, Longitude from Vehicles WHERE Latitude IS NOT NULL AND LONGITUDE IS NOT NULL AND Division = @Division and Terminal = @Terminal and vehicleID LIKE '1334'";
                var CompanyAll = CompanyAllString;
                //var Division = "PET";
                //var Terminal = "RSM";                               


                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CompanyAll, con))
                    {

                        con.Open();

                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Division", Division);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terminal", Terminal);
                        da.Fill(dt);




                        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                        Dictionary<string, object> row;
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                            }
                            rows.Add(row);
                        }


                        return serializer.Serialize(rows);

                    }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is using ajax technology to call backend service to get your new data

so what you need to do is:

use jquery to get your result from your page method

1. modify your pagemethod so it return the object - you don't need to serialize it, it is done automaticaly
2. use jquery to get data from the pagemethod

### 1. modify page method

```
// change your return type
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> TeleMatics()
{
    // same as before
    // but return the object you want - no seralization needed

    return rows
}
```

### 2. use jquery to get data

in your `display` function where you do `addressPointsTeleMatics = JSON.parse('<%=TeleMatics() %>');` change it so that jquery
get result from the page method, something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourPage.aspx/TeleMatics",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
}).success(function (data) {
    addressPointsTeleMatics = data.d
})
```

note Page Method default accept post - if you want to use get (which you should), add declaration `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` to the method

more info about jquery call page method, checkout

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

---

## below was my original answer, personaly I prefer use generic handler - keep it just for reference

1. create a generic handler (ashx) which will return your new query data
2. use jquery to get ajax result from the ashx you created on step 1 then referesh result

something like:

### 1. create generic handler

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        // your TeleMatics method
        ....

        // write to response instead of direct return 
        context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows););  
    }
}
```

### 2. use jquery to get ajax result

in your `display` function where you do `addressPointsTeleMatics = JSON.parse('<%=TeleMatics() %>');` change it so that jquery
get result from the generic handler, something like:

```
$.getJSON("url to your handler", function(data){
    addressPointsTeleMatics = data;
})
```

if you need pass data to the handler you can use querystring